# Configure permissions to execute an especific job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a little doubt about the behavior the permissions jobs in jenkins. My problem is that I want to configure a job for it can be builded for an user/s with permissions for it. The permissions will be granted for me. It wish an configurable option for each job.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Whit this plugin you can set permission by pattern.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin

E.g: Pattern = "Producion-.*"
You can set permissions to a user to execute builds only when the jobs-name starts with Production-